# While loop test

Tags: python, string, loops, while-loop, boolean

I'm not getting the desired results with this Python code. Need help.

The while loop is supposed to stop when you put in string that meets the criteria.

Code:

```
x = input("Enter input: ")

while (int(x[3]) != 1 or int(x[3]) != 2):
    print("The fourth character must be a 1 or 2")
    x = input("Enter input again: ")
```

Comment: It looks like that `or` should be an `and`.

Comment: Any number you enter will always be unequal to either 1 or 2, so the condition always succeeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a number is always unequal to 1 or to 2, you probably want to use `and`:

```
x = input("Enter input: ")

while int(x[3]) != 1 and int(x[3]) != 2:
    print("The fourth character must be a 1 or 2")
    x = input("Enter input again: ")
```

using `not in` is more readable:

```
x = input("Enter input: ")

while int(x[3]) not in (1, 2):
    print("The fourth character must be a 1 or 2")
    x = input("Enter input again: ")
```

if you want a more fail tolerant way, compare with strings:

```
while True:
    x = input("Enter input: ")
    if x[3:4] in ('1', '2'):
        break
    print("The fourth character must be a 1 or 2.")
```

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation makes sense